# how to customize hello dolly plugin?

Tags: plugins, php

I am trying to play with the Hello Dolly plugin. I want that plugin to work on the front end. Is it possible to bring Hello Dolly to the front end? Or will that affect my existing website?

Answer (score 6):

In your theme, add a custom action in a template where you want to show the output:

```
do_action( 'show_lyrics' );
```

This does nothing for itself. Now you can add the function `hello_dolly` as a  callback for that action in your `functions.php`:

```
if ( function_exists( 'hello_dolly' ) ) {
    add_action( 'show_lyrics', 'hello_dolly' );
}
```